# How to add a button without creating a new window from another class

Tags: java, awt

Maybe I am understanding this concept totally wrong but I am trying to create classes for buttons and have them called in a main GUI class so they appear on that window but I don't exactly know how to call these button classes to the main GUI class.

I'm currently creating them by simply making a new object but this creates a new window instead of adding it to the currently existing window in my main GUI class. How do I fix this or am I doing this totally wrong?

---

### GUI class

```
            import java.awt.*;
            import java.awt.event.*;
            import javax.swing.*;

            class GUI extends Frame implements WindowListener
            {

                public GUI()
                {
                    super("GUI");

                    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
                    addWindowListener(this);


                }

                public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent event){}
                public void windowIconified(WindowEvent event){} 
                public void windowActivated(WindowEvent event){} 
                public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent event){}
                public void windowOpened(WindowEvent event){} 
                public void windowClosed(WindowEvent event)  {}
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) { System.exit(0); }

                public static void main(String[] args)
                {
                    GUI screen = new GUI();

                    new Button1("TEST");

                    screen.setSize(500,100);
                    screen.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    screen.setVisible(true);
                }
            }
```

---

### Button1 class

```
            import java.awt.*;
            import java.awt.event.*;

            public class Button1 extends GUI implements ActionListener {

                private Button addButton;

                public Button1(String s) {
                    addButton = new Button(s);
                    add(addButton);
                    addButton.addActionListener(this);
                    setVisible(true);
                    System.out.println("It atleast works here");
                }

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("It works - Button1");
                }

                public static void main(String[] args) {

                }
            }
```

Comment: why AWT, and in this millenium

Comment: @mKorbel I'm required to use AWT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: Why do you actually want to create new Classes for every button?
Second: Yes i think you didn't get it quite right. This code should do what you want. If you don't get it, just read or watch a tutorial about object oriented programming in Java.

```
import java.awt.*;
        import java.awt.event.*;
        import javax.swing.*;

        class GUI extends Frame implements WindowListener
        {

            public GUI()
            {
                super("GUI");

                setLayout(new FlowLayout());
                addWindowListener(this);
            }

            public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent event){}
            public void windowIconified(WindowEvent event){} 
            public void windowActivated(WindowEvent event){} 
            public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent event){}
            public void windowOpened(WindowEvent event){} 
            public void windowClosed(WindowEvent event)  {}
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) { System.exit(0); }

            public static void main(String[] args)
            {
                GUI screen = new GUI();

                screen.setSize(500,100);
                Button button1 = new Button("Button 1");
                button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    System.out.println("It works - Button1");
                });
                screen.add(button1);
                screen.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                screen.setVisible(true);
            }
        }
```